# How to write continued fraction as polynomial?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, continued-fractions

I have

\begin{align}
r(x)=  1 + \frac{x}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x-1}{-1+\frac{x+1}{1+\frac{x-1}{-1}}}}
\end{align}

for an interpolation problem, and I need to write $r(x)$ such that nominator and denominator are polynomials. Wolfram Alpha gave me $r(x) = \frac{x+4}{4-x}$ for $x \neq 3$, but I don't know how to do it without computing software.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The general approach is to start at the bottom and work up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We follow @Mark's suggestion and define $s(x)$ via

$$\begin{align}
r(x)=  1 + \frac{x}{-\frac{1}{2}+s(x)}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
s(x)=  1 +\frac{x-1}{-1+\frac{x+1}{1+\frac{x-1}{-1...}}}
\end{align}$$

Now we replace $1+\frac{x-1}{*}$ in the denominator of the right hand side of the previous equation and obtain:

$$\begin{align}
s(x)=  1 +\frac{x-1}{-1+\frac{x+1}{s(x)}}
\end{align}$$

We can now solve the $s(x)$ from the last equation and substitute it into the first equation to solve for $r(x)$.

-mike